# Lost .m files after XCode crash

Tags: xcode5.1

I am on the verge of a nervous breakdown. I am currently working on a project in XCode, which suddenly crashed on Build.
When I restarted XCode, two of my .m files had totally disapeared. Sadly, I hadn't yet commited…
Any ideas if it is possible to recover these files ?

Comment: Do you not have a Time Machine backup ?

Comment: Disappeared in XCode, or disappeared in the filesystem (in Finder, Terminal)?

Comment: @Paul : no. No recent enough Time Machine Backup. The files are one week old…

Comment: @Evert : XCode shows them in red…
I've searched the Finer AND the Terminal but to no avail.
XCode simply crashed with a warning of insufficient disc space. So I made space and when I restarted XCode it had deleted the two files I was working on.